# Gmail received in our app using gmail api or another way in android

Tags: android

I have create Gmail app using Gmail api but i am cofusing how to received mail get in background and forground so please tell me any solution.

Comment: You must provide some work and research that you have done in order to get some help.

Comment: this time not any work done but i am RND for google cloud using gmail receiving mail in this url https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/mail/receiving-mail-with-mail-api